# How to compare two dates based on Month and Year only in python

Tags: python

I need to compare two dates based on month and year only, without considering the day or time. I tried following but it does not give correct result:

```
if lastMonthAllowed.month > lastUserUploadMonth.month and lastMonthAllowed.year > lastUserUploadMonth.year:
    #do something
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Any simpler than that - I don't think so. But correct version would be: `if lastMonthAllowed.year > lastUserUploadMonth.year or (lastMonthAllowed.year == lastUserUploadMonth.year and lastMonthAllowed.month > lastUserUploadMonth.month):` (months only matter if years are equal).

Comment: @CristiFati Why not build tuples and let *them* do that?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: that would yield nicer (and much shorter - but slower) code, but I kept it explicit (so the rationale to be obvious), then in terms of implementation.... sky is the limit!

Comment: @CristiFati I had something similar in my mind too but I was looking something even more refined that wouldn't require changes every time I have to compare dates using a different operator like `==, >=, <=`. Your solution works fine, but I'm gonna go with @tk78 answer.

Comment: Sure, as you wish. But you'll have to use such an operator (`>=`) anyway, and in that case Stefan's *tuple* suggestion: `if (lastMonthAllowed.year, lastMonthAllowed.month) >= (lastUserUploadMonth.year, lastUserUploadMonth.month):` is simpler, shorter, nicer, faster, and more natural. Anyway, I didn't understand the "*require changes every time I have to compare dates*" part from your last comment. None of the 2 expressions require changes depending on dates.

Comment: @CristiFati I suggest you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
import datetime

def trunc_datetime(someDate):
    return someDate.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

a = trunc_datetime(datetime.datetime(2018,1,15))
b = trunc_datetime(datetime.datetime(2018,1,20))

print(a == b)
>>>True
```

Comment: At the return in the function you need to tab it. Because otherwise you get **IndentationError: expected an indented block**

Answer (score 2):

You could use `datetime.datetime`, which has a `year` and a `month` attribute. [Check this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer accordingly.